# Is it true that if $(n\Delta s_n)$ is bounded then $(s_n)$ is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(s_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers and $\Delta s_n=s_n-s_{n-1}.$  Is the following always true?

> If $(n\Delta s_n)$ is bounded then $(s_n)$ is bounded.

Comment: $s_n=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i\nabla s_i}{i}$, which gives you condition on $n\Delta s_n$ for $s_n$ to be bounded. Just going down to zero isn't enough either - it has to be relatively fast. Sidenote: $\Delta$ is used for forward difference and $\nabla$ for backward (your definition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not true.

Consider $H_n$ the partial sums of the harmonic series.

Then $n\Delta H_n$ is bounded by $1$ , yet $H_n$ goes to $\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k$. Then $$Δs_n=\frac1n$$ hence $nΔs_n=1$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$ but $s_n\to +\infty$.